# Is my Windows partition too far down on the disk?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, partitioning, grub

I have `/boot/` on `/dev/sda1` (1GB), followed by my Linux root LVM on `/dev/sda2` (1.3GB). Finally, I freshly installed Windows 7 on `/dev/sda3` in the remaining 700GB of space.

When I select Windows 7 in the grub menu, I get something like the following error and am thrown to grub4dos:

```
find --set-root --ignore-floppies --ignore-cd /bootmgr

Error 15: file not found
Unable to locate necessary tables for adjustment.
```

None of the options in grub4dos return anything but the above error, and I've only seen Error 5 or other errors that don't seem to be relevant on other related sites. I heard that 1TB is the upper limit for locating Windows 7 partitions; is this true? How can I fix the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know the source of the error, repartitioning and putting the Windows install at the beginning of the disk is a valid workaround, for anyone who stumbles across this.